# How can I tell emacs to choose the 'right' link function from `org-store-link-functions` based on the mode it was triggered in

Tags: org-capture, org-link

Whenever I want to capture a link from a PDFView buffer with `org-store-link`, I get prompted for the link type I wish to apply (*"Which function for creating the link? "*), with two choices: `org-pdftools-store-link` or `org-git-store-link`. I would like emacs to always choose the `org-pdftools` link type when I capture from a pdf buffer and the `org-git` link type when I capture from any other buffer that is not a pdf buffer (plain text etc.)

Is there a simple way to do this?

`org-pdftools-store-link` is defined in the `org-pdftools` package and `org-git-store-link` is defined in `ol-git-link.el` in `org-plus-contrib`.